# правильная обработка дескрипторов после select

Tags: linux, c, сокет, select, tcp-ip

Есть tcp сокет сервер. К нему может подключиться неограниченное количество клиентов. После всех подключений дескриптор каждого подключения заносится в `fd_set readfds`, вызывается `select(n, &readfds, NULL,NULL,NULL);`

Вопрос: `select` вызывается в цикле, что делать если в `readfds` после возврата из `select` будет несколько дескрипторов? Обработать один и идти на следующую итерацию основного цикла или обработать все имеющиеся? Вот 2 кода, для них есть общий односвязный список(fds) с дескрипторами, правильно 1 или 2 вариант?:

1: то есть тут мы обработаем все дескрипторы с которых пришли данные

```
select(n, &readfds, NULL, NULL, NULL);
for (f = fds; f; f = f->next) {
    if (FD_ISSET(f->fd, &readfds)) {
        *что-то далаем*
    }
}
```

2: а тут один

```
select(n, &readfds, NULL, NULL, NULL);
for (f = fds; f; f = f->next) {
    if (FD_ISSET(f->fd, &readfds)) {
        *что-то далаем*;
        break; // выход из этого цикла после первого ответа и возврат к основному циклу
    }
}
```

По теории (как я понял): возврат в основной цикл делаем после одного ответа, в таком случае правильным будет код под номером 2, я его и придерживаюсь, это логично, что бы мы сразу могли принять соединение следующего клиента и не образовывалась очередь. Но вдруг я ошибаюсь. Извините если банальнища какая-то, я изучаю и меня интересуют все нюансы.

Comment: Обычно, с целью уменьшения количества системных вызовов и реинициализаций  `readfds` используют вариант 1. (не знаю, где вы прочли теорию о  логичности варианта 2). Более того, если следовать варианту 2, то теоретически возможна ситуация, когда некоторые соединения вообще лишатся обслуживания.

Comment: Вообще, select был хорош лет 30-40 назад, когда количество дескрипторов укладывалось в 64 и можно было делать реинициализацию 2-мя присваиваниями. Сейчас лучше посмотреть на poll (или не полениться и изучить для  linux [epoll](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/epoll.7.html))

Comment: @avp, да, про epoll я в курсе. А по поводу второго варианта - информация в книге описывает событийно-ориентированное программирование, на одно событие одно действиие и возврат в основной цикл, примеров с множеством событий, пришедшими одновремменно, я в той книге не увидел, вот и сделал индуктивный вывод. Этот вывод мне кажется плохим только, как вы сказали, из-за реинициализаций, согласен, это долго и нагружено. Но в остальном ведь это довольно таки правильно: лучше подождут ответ, чем подождут соединение?))

Comment: @avp, книга: А.В. Столяров "Программирование. Введение в профессию: системы и сети." Часть 6. 6.4.4 Выборка событий в ОС Unix: вызов select и 6.4.5 Сеанс работы как конечный автомат - эти темы. Не исключаю, что я неправильно понял.

Comment: @avp, ну, да... На одно событие одно действие, я это понял как в принципе максимум одно событие можно обработать, событий может произойти и 100 за раз, каждому одно действие... Вот пока вопрос не задашь и прям не подумаешь, перечитывая его или комментарии, иногда, фиг поймешь... Но все же принцип, который я придумал себе: лучше подождут ответ, чем соединение - не дает мне покоя, стоит ли в нем разубедиться?

Comment: Если приоритет нового соединения самый высокий, то ничто же не мешает проверить и обработать его сразу после возврата из select. Потом в цикле обработать остальные события и после всего вызвать select снова. Кстати, длинные ответы (если вы не делаете сокеты неблокирующими), возможно, стоит отправлять из отдельного потока.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144827/discussion-between-nx4n-and-avp).